# Facebook Login with Parse returns ParseUser == null after Facebook login

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, parse-platform

I'm currently developing an android app with Parse. One part of my app is a social login component. I can start the facebook login dialog just fine and use it with my facebook credentials. Once the Facebook Login finishes, nothing happens. I've looked in the debugger and I found out that the ParseUser varaible is still null after the Facebook login. This is my class code.

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.myapp.myapp_app.NavigationDraw;
import com.myapp.myapp_app.R;
import com.myapp.myapp_app.Welcome;
import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.parse.LogInCallback;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;
import com.parse.SignUpCallback;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class LoginSignupActivity extends Fragment {

private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

public static LoginSignupActivity newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
    LoginSignupActivity logsign = new LoginSignupActivity();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
    return logsign;
}

private Dialog progressDialog;

//Facebook-Login
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ParseFacebookUtils.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
Button loginbutton;
Button signup;
Button facebookloginbutton;
String usernametxt;
String passwordtxt;
EditText password;
EditText username;
ParseUser user = new ParseUser();


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)  {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loginsignup, container, false);

    username = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.password);

    loginbutton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.login);
    signup = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.signup);
    facebookloginbutton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.facebook_login);

    loginbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            usernametxt = username.getText().toString();
            passwordtxt = password.getText().toString();

            ParseUser.logInInBackground(usernametxt, passwordtxt,
                    new LogInCallback() {
                        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                            if (user != null) {
                                // Fragmentwechsel
                                final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                ft.replace(R.id.container, new Welcome(), "NewFragmentTag");
                                ft.commit();
                            } else {

                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
    signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Fragmentwechsel
            final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.container, new SignupActivity(), "NewFragmentTag");
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            ft.commit();
        }
    });

    facebookloginbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email");

            ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(getActivity(), permissions, new LogInCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
                    if (user == null) {
                        Log.d("MyApp", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
                    } else if (user.isNew()) {
                        Log.d("MyApp", "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
                        showUserProfile();
                    } else {
                        Log.d("MyApp", "User logged in through Facebook!");
                        showUserProfile();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

private void createFacebookUser() {
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                    if (jsonObject != null) {
                        JSONObject userProfile = new JSONObject();

                        try {
                            user.put("facebookId", jsonObject.getLong("id"));
                            user.setUsername(jsonObject.getString("name"));

                            if (jsonObject.getString("email") != null)
                                user.setEmail(jsonObject.getString("email"));

                            user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                                public void done(ParseException e) {
                                    if (e == null) {
                                        // Fragmentwechsel
                                        final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                        ft.replace(R.id.container, new Welcome(), "NewFragmentTag");
                                        ft.commit();
                                        // Infoanzeige, dass Anmeldung erfolgreich war
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                                getResources().getString(R.string.signup_success),
                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                                getResources().getString(R.string.error),
                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                            // Show the user info
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.d(ParseApplication.TAG,
                                    "Error parsing returned user data. " + e);
                        }
                    } else if (graphResponse.getError() != null) {
                        switch (graphResponse.getError().getCategory()) {
                            case LOGIN_RECOVERABLE:
                                Log.d(ParseApplication.TAG,
                                        "Authentication error: " + graphResponse.getError());
                                break;

                            case TRANSIENT:
                                Log.d(ParseApplication.TAG,
                                        "Transient error. Try again. " + graphResponse.getError());
                                break;

                            case OTHER:
                                Log.d(ParseApplication.TAG,
                                        "Some other error: " + graphResponse.getError());
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    request.executeAsync();
}

private void showUserProfile(){
    final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.container, new TestProfile(), "NewFragmentTag");
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    ft.commit();
    }
}
```

I've also did everything suggested by the facebook und parse guides to set up the login.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I found same problem but no any solution was found.. this problem is facing after update the facebook.  In my solution simple login with facebook then login with parse.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line

```
ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(context);
```

in **onCreateView** and try

[Read This Documentation carefully](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#users-facebook-users)